# Vertically centering a piece of text inside a div

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I've seen tons of tuts on how to do this but none of them are working for me.  I'm trying to center my name inside a div (identified as ".banner").

Here is the code:

```
//html///////////////////////////////////
<div class="banner">
    <p>Jake Demian_</p>
</div>


//css////////////////////////////////////
.banner
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #e8bc23;
    text-align: center;
}

.banner p
{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "courier new";
    margin: 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

jsfiddle link:  [linkage](http://jsfiddle.net/BTjr7/)

Sorry for the minimal information.  I've tried every combination of `inline-block`, `vertical-align: middle`, `height 100%`, `margin: auto` that I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
top:45%;
position:relative;
```

to `.banner p`.

You could also try adding:

```
display: table;
```

to `.banner` and

```
display: table-cell;
```

to `.banner p`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BTjr7/2/